# Azure Synapse dedicated pool, table created by the system?

Tags: azure-synapse

Some tables are created by the system from times to times, naming convention is T_9999_string_of_32, examples:
T_7407_a67cacd3c8734031bac00ce8a45db218
T_7441_d8498f681e574830a7a1a659dcce1dc9

They are empty, their structures match the tables we're creating.
Anybody knows why they are created ?

We just drop them, we're still in dev but in prod soon, and it will be complexed to drop them in prod if we have that behavior.

```
The automatically created tables are a copy of existing tables 
plus a new last column also generated, example: 
CREATE TABLE [dim].[T_6340_7e49b0e3f2f449f2be9487adfcd9aa33]  (
    [num_institution] [int]  NULL,
    [dsc_institution] [nvarchar](50)  NULL,
    [tms_debut_version] [datetime2](7)  NULL,
    [tms_fin_version] [datetime2](7)  NULL,
    [tms_insertion] [datetime2](7)  NULL,
    [rd40f6e327a9f4e3a8137716dada51956] [int]  NULL
)

It seems to be a working/temp tables not being dropped after 
Synapse doing something.
```

Comment: please provide screen shots and table schema

Comment: temporary tables exist at the session level do you see them even after closing the session?

Comment: Yes tables are still there.
We have to drop them manually.